# Htaccess caching doesnt cache everything

Tags: .htaccess

i'm trying to cache everything 'which google pagespeed says' with htaccess. Pagespeed showing 67 errors to me before htaccess cache. When i put caching codes to htaccess, pagespeed shows 59 errors. For example i have 5 css files but htaccess caching only 2 of them. Not caching some webp, css, js, png files (59 total).

```
My htaccess:
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    # One year for image and video files
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|mp4|mpeg|png|svg|swf|webp|js|pdf|woff|ttf|css|woff2)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

I found solution with cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

The caching policy on my website is

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|gz|ttf|webp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Be sure that your server is getting the changes, in case try to reboot it, even if modifying `.htaccess` should not require a restart

Comment: its not about reboot because its works for few files (67 decreasing to 59)

Comment: @Cihan which files are not been "effected" by the cache policy? sure that the 59 file remaining are not images/icons/fonts ecc ecc?